# Windows Modern UI Message App Guide

Tags: c#, android, xaml, windows-store-apps, chat

I'm working on a Windows Store Message Application Project.

Basically, this project consists of two app.

The first is on Android (for now) and will act as a bridge to the user computer running Windows (8.1). All SMS & MMS are transfered via Bluetooth (hence 8.1 only due to need for Bluetooth)

The Second app, is the main one, running on the computer. At the end, the user can start using the Windows App to text (MMS later) with people. No cloud servers involded here, that's the main point.

My question is simple. I can see quite a few Windows Store app (Metro app) out there with nice UI for conversation (chat / messaging). I don't want to be as good as them, because I lake the skill of a good designer but I really seem to have trouble designing a simple conversation app.

To be more precisded, I am looking on guides to do :

1. Chat bubble (on the left for received messages, right for sent messages) ;
2. Smooth animations on a ListView/ListBox (so far using ´ScrollIntoView´ makes ListView blink... which is disturbing)

That's "it" for now.
Any help is more than welcome ! Thanks !!

PS: I found something close : http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/07/15/a-wp7-conversation-view.html but does not work for W8.1 :( But now you know what I am looking for ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the chart bubble, you can use canvas to draw it out.
[image]

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="GridAppDemo.Controls.MyChatBubble"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GridAppDemo.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="306" Height="104">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-10,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Border Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,5">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <Canvas>
                    <Polygon Fill="Green" Points="0, 5, 10, 10, 0, 15" />
                </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,0" ></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25">
                <Canvas>
                    <Polygon Fill="Green" Points="0, 10, 10, 5, 10, 15" />
                </Canvas>
                <Border Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,5" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you !! That's a good start ! But how can I adapt the polygon width and height regarding the message content ?